# Loadframe Fails at CreateEx for no apparent reason in CMainFrame

Tags: visual-c++, user-interface, mfc

Okay so my MFC application was working fairly well until I cleared the application from the system registry. Now I am unable to run the program. Whenever I try running the program I get an exception. Checking the stack I noticed that CreateEx in LoadFrame for CMainFrame was crushing. This crash occurs when ProcessShellCommand is called in the derived CwinApp of the application.However, I have not been able to pinpoint the exact cause of the crash. I have a hunch it might have something to do with the loading of resource but I don't know exactly how. I have checked the .rc include file and it looks fine to me. I just don't understand how clearing the registry could cause such a mess. Been at it for the past 4 hours.
So basically I am asking if any of you have faced this problem before, and how did you managed to fix it without starting right from scratch? I am not sure of the exact part of the code I should put here to clarify my question so I hope this is clear enough. 
Thanks

Comment: Why not set a breakpoint in `LoadFrame` and then either look at the stack or single-step the application until you do get a crash? Then look at what is being done and the answer will reveal itself to you!

Comment: I already stepped through the application and what I realized it somewhere within the CWnd CreateEx function I fall into a loop and the pointer lpzsWindowsName degenerates into a bad pointer for no clear reason. I am sure this is a common problem people face, I just don't know how to fix it yet

Comment: I doubt it's a common problem. But if you can see the steps leading up to failure you should be able to see *exactly* what the code is trying to do at that point, which would suggest where to look. I'll bet you that you removed string from the string table.

Comment: Please define "crash". Is is assertion that fired or some illegal operation?
Registry changes should not cause this problem.
Are you getting any error message?